# having models directory and AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: django, model

I have `myApp/models/profiles.py` instead of `myApp/models.py` (to group related models)

How do you set **AUTH_USER_MODEL** in this case?

Because auth accepts only "foo.bar" pattern.

```
   app_label, model_name = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.split('.')
```

Comment: Try adding `from profiles import *` to `myApp/models/__init__.py` and then using `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myApp.MyModel'`

Comment: I get different error "ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'common.CusomUser' that has not been installed"

Comment: oh shoot me.. Cus T om User..

Comment: I've posted my information as an answer. You should accept whichever helped you for the sake of anyone who lands here from Google :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django expects the models for any given app to be in `app.models`. If you want to use this kind of file structure, you'll need to still make sure this is the case. The easiest way to do this is too add `from profiles import *` in `myApp/models/__init__.py` and then use `AUTH_USER_MODEL` as normal.

For example, you you had `myApp/models/profiles.py` and `myApp/models/actions.py` your `myApp/models/__init__.py` should read

```
from profiles import *
from actions import *
```

Remember to make sure you don't have any name conflicts too, and you may wish to use set your [`__all__`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package) value in each of your sub-packages.

Comment: oh. nice to know that __all__ is to explicitly list what names you want to export from the package. Thanks

Comment: you are a life saver man, this took me hours

Comment: this worked for me when I used a dot before the module name. " from .profiles import * "

Answer (score 0):

You can either pass the class directly or the 'app.model'. django only registers classes defined in `app.models` module, so you'll need to import the class in `models` `init`. Since you'll be importing the model in `init` anyway, you don't need to specify the full path to the class in the foreignkey.