# I want to target AUTH_USER_MODEL to a custom user model in sub directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

my project structure is like below:

```
./apps
./apps/bizusers
./apps/bizusers/admin.py
./apps/bizusers/apps.py
./apps/bizusers/models.py
./apps/bizusers/serializers.py
./apps/bizusers/tests.py
./apps/bizusers/views.py
./apps/bizusers/__init__.py
./apps/__init__.py
./config
./config/asgi.py
./config/settings.py
./config/urls.py
./config/wsgi.py
./config/__init__.py
./manage.py
./requirements.txt
```

My custom user model is in

> ./apps/bizusers/models.py

I have this in settings:

> INSTALLED_APPS = [
> 'apps', ]

I added `AUTH_USER_MODEL = "bizusers.User"` in settings.py

I have tried to edit `./apps/__init__.py` and `./apps/bizusers/apps.py` but I cannot get it to work.

I have tried these solutions below:

[having models directory and AUTH_USER_MODEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19698950/having-models-directory-and-auth-user-model)

[Model in sub-directory via app_label?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2480060/model-in-sub-directory-via-app-label)

['MyAppConfig' must supply a name attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37741672/myappconfig-must-supply-a-name-attribute/37744611#37744611)

Thanks.

Comment: what is your app name?

Comment: bizusers or apps?

Comment: Hi @daneilJames, the name of the app is bizusers. I created a folder 'apps' to contain all my apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have your apps as subpackages of another package, but then you do need to add your app to the `INSTALLED_APPS` list, i.e. instead of adding `apps` you need to be adding the subpackages of it in the list:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'apps.bizusers',
]
```

Next your setting for `AUTH_USER_MODEL` is correct:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "bizusers.User"
```

Comment: Hi @Abdul, I get this error `AttributeError: Manager isn't available; 'auth.User' has been swapped for 'bizusers.User'`

Comment: @AatishKumar that means this setting did work, you now get this error because you try to use the default user model somewhere in your code. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67294774/edit) and add the full stack trace of this error to your question.

Comment: yes, i realised that just after i put my comment. Thank you. :)